# Security and ngMockE2E

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ngmocke2e

I have some protractor tests and I would like to mock some calls to a third party service used by my Angular JS app.

I've read about [ngMockE2E](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E). My understanding is this requires I add angular-mocks.js to my page.

What are the best practices including angular-mocks.js in a page? Should I use some sort of pre-processor to remove it or is it somehow safe for use in a production environment?

Answer (score 2):

Protractor allows you to add arbitrary mock modules via [`browser.addMockModule()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.addMockModule) (which would though still require `angular-mocks` module to be loaded). Sample usages:

- [Protractor addMockModule and $httpProvider interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259746/protractor-addmockmodule-and-httpprovider-interceptor)
- [Using Protractor mocks for AngurlarJS tests without backend](https://www.majormojo.co.uk/blog/using-protractor-mocks-pt-2.html)

> Should I use some sort of pre-processor to remove it or is it somehow safe for use in a production environment?

I would solve it on the application build level (with `grunt` or `gulp`, for example). Install `angular-mocks` package and include in the build only for the dev/test environment.

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. The second reference says "it is essential that the script angular-mocks.js is referenced in your AngularJS application". Are you saying that's not the case?

Comment: @objectuser from what I know of, angular-mocks are not needed for that to work. Please check.

Comment: I followed the second link and it works with angular-mocks.js included in the HTML file but not without it.